# storing to and loading from files. XML (XElement) or other?

Tags: c#, list, file-io

I have a couple of lists in my program and wanted to get your take on how to manage it (store and load).

These are the lists:

1. An `IDictionary` where the values are instances of class Element. I fill this `IDictionary` using a for loop that dynamically creates new instances of the `Element` class. `Element` contains variables such as `_label`, `_value`, `_pointers`.
2. An `IDictionary` similar to the one above that is called `Skill`. The `Skill` class contains variables such as `_cast`, `_recast`, `_MPCost`.
3. Three classes: `RouteManager`, `Route` and `Waypoint`. `RouteManager` contains a list of instances of class `Route`, and `Route` contains a list of instances of class `Waypoint`. So I can pick out a particular point by going: `_routeManager[0]._routes[0]._waypoints[0]`.

I currently populate these lists with data I have hardcoded in the program. For instance when creating new elements I write this in a loop:

```
iDict[names[i]].Value = new Element(_label[i], _value[i], _pointers[i]),
```

The problem is that it is highly inconvenient to keep all these lists: `Label[] _label, int[] _value, int[] _pointers`, in the program itself. I want to have it all be stored in the file system instead.

Therefore, the question: How would you recommend doing that?

Comment: There are simply too many ways of doing it - depending on the file format that you choose, the API that you prefer, and so on. Try an one of them - for example, LINQ2XML may be a decent choice. If you get stuck, post a question with some code and a sample XML.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".